# Can I get information from other filesystems from overlayfs?

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, overlayfs

Can you solve the problem of not knowing the inode information when **modifying the path of upperdir** in overlayfs?

After changing the upperdir path:

```
root@bcd0d4e391f8:~/myDir# ls -i   
ls: cannot access 'ssd.c': No such file or directory  
ls: cannot access 'ssd.abc': No such file or directory  
? ssd.abc  ? ssd.c
```

*The upperdir path was modified by changing the overlayfs code.

---

*Original code

```
static int ovl_create_upper(struct dentry *dentry, struct inode *inode,
            struct ovl_cattr *attr){    

    struct dentry *upperdir = ovl_dentry_upper(dentry->d_parent);
    struct inode *udir = upperdir->d_inode;
    struct dentry *newdentry;
    int err;

    newdentry = ovl_create_real(udir,
                lookup_one_len(dentry->d_name.name,
                       upperdir,
                       dentry->d_name.len),
                attr);
```

*Fix code example

```
static int ovl_create_upper(struct dentry *dentry, struct inode *inode,
            struct ovl_cattr *attr){
     struct dentry *upperdir = ovl_dentry_upper(dentry->d_parent);
     struct inode *udir = upperdir->d_inode;
     struct dentry *newdentry;
     int err;
     extern struct qsh_metadata qsh_mt; //HOON  

     newdentry = ovl_create_real(qsh_mt.qsh_dentry->d_inode,
            lookup_one_len(dentry->d_name.name,
                    qsh_mt.qsh_dentry,
                    dentry->d_name.len),
                attr);
```

*In the above code, I replaced the upperdir part with the disk I want and the mounted dentry object.
*extern struct qsh_metadata qsh_mt; => Code I added

ex) struct dentry upperdir = qsh_dentry;
    docker base mount : /dev/sda
    qsh_dentry : mount /dev/sdb

Comment: What exactly did you change?  How are you testing this?  Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Thanks for reading.
I uploaded the question again.